# Edit string in a file

Tags: python

I am trying to edit the word I typed and update it to a new word or string however the below code is updating but deleting the other string that are not edited

Ex: I have

```
a
b
c
```

And I edit `a` I typed `aa` as new string for `a`
then it will only show aa and the rest is gone.

```
  input = raw_input("Input word to edit: ") 
  with open('workfile.txt', 'r') as myfile:
      data=myfile.read()
      if input in data:
         Newword=raw_input("New: ")
          data=Newword
         f = open("workfile.txt","w")  
         f.writelines(data) 
          print "Data has been edited !\n"   

      else:
          print "ERROR!"
```

Comment: `open("workfile.txt","w")` will **always** clear the entire file.

Answer (score 0):

With this line:

```
data=Newword
```

all you're doing is setting the whole `data` to just what the user typed. You should use [`str.replace()`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_replace.htm) :

```
data = data.replace(input,Newword)
```